# How to appropriately reverse-proxy nodejs subroutes?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am new to nodejs and nginx as well. So what I am trying to do is reverse-proxy node in nginx. I am able to do so but my subsequent routes from nodejs doesn't get reverse-proxied.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
});

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    upload(req, res, (err) => {
        console.log(req.file);
        res.render('index' , {
            msg: 'File Uploaded!',
            file : `uploads/${req.file.filename}`
        }); 
    });
});
```

So here is the basic code. '/' has the index page with a button. And when you click on the button it goes to the '/upload'.

It works without reverse proxy.
My reverse proxy is configured as below.

```
location /nodeAdmin/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

So now when I go to mydomain.com/nodeAdmin I see the 'index'. But when I click on the upload button, I need to go to /upload of nodejs app but it goes to mydomain.com/upload which does not exist.

It would be great if someone could direct me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue lies in the html.

Your current html may have something like

```
<a href="/upload">upload</a>
```

Making all the links "relative" should solve your problem

```
<a href="./upload">upload</a>
```

Links starting with `/` will be relative to the domain, while links starting with `./` will be relative to the current directory (`nodeAdmin`).